# android: different ways to set fontFamily

Tags: android, font-family

I have this `TextView`

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:contentDescription="...."
            android:text="text"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black4"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"/>
```

If I use `android:fontFamily` it doesn't set the right font. What is the difference between the `android:` and `app:` version. Also what happens when I set `app:font="@font/lato_regular"`?

Comment: Do you have your font in the folder 'preloaded_fonts.xml'?

Answer (score 0):

`android` namespace is used in order to access and use the attributes which are provided by the Android platform.

`app` namespace is used to access the custom attributes which are defined in the application scope.

The app namespace is not specific to a library, but it is used for all attributes defined in your app, whether by your code or by libraries you import, effectively making a single global namespace for custom attributes - i.e., attributes not defined by the android system.

*Based on [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-xmlns-app-and-xmlns-Android)*